# how to add vertical itext using fabric js

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I want to enter vertical fonts in IText object.
like this:

```
v
e
r
t
i
c
a
l
```

Please help!

[image]

Comment: where is your effort

Comment: @manetsus,Thanks for your replay.IText can set new line by '\n',and [https://jsfiddle.net/af7aqeo7/].

Comment: add it in the question as edit

Answer (score 0):

You have to set "\n"

```
var textUser = new fabric.IText('I\nl\no\nv\ne\nf\nabricjs', { ... options });
```